# What is wrong with my "new" camera? My playback looks bad

Tags: video, canon, video-standards

My old Canon mv690 camera recorder got broken. It uses MiniDV casettes. To play many old recordings I bought a used Canon GL2 Mini DV 3ccd camera to play my old casettes, but the image is not displaying correctly. Does anyone know what the problem can be?

This is what my videos looks like on the GL2 Camera: 
[image]

Comment: Looks like a video decoding problem. I mean, looks like the problem is NOT physical, but digital. Digital tape may be the same, but the digital format may not. Check with the specs of both cameras what format are they recording and playing and if you can set the play to different formats/codecs/whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try cleaning the playheads (there are special tapes you can put in for cleaning) and/or checking the playback speed.  Those are the two most common causes of that issue on my GL2.

Comment: when I do test recording with the GL2, the playback works fine,so i think i dont have too clean the playheads. How can I change the playspeed?

Comment: I believe it is in the playback or vcr menu but I'd have to double check. It'll be lp and ep as modes I believe. I'll try to dig out my GL2 and check tonight.

Comment: Seems like my old camera was recording in another format PAL, and I can not make it to work with the GL

Comment: @VidarVestnes - ah, that would also do it.  Yeah, you need a PAL compatible playback deck and unfortunately the GL2 won't change modes.  You might be able to get around it by using a firewire connection and trying to playback to the computer and decode it as PAL, but I'm not sure if that will work or not.